# Perl -check for uninitialized value

Tags: perl, unix

I am doing the below in a perl script:

```
my @pm1_CS_missing_months = `sqlplus -s $connstr \@DLmissing_months.sql`;
```

it takes the output of an sql query.
if i have to check for no rows selected,how could i do it?
i want to do like this:

```
if(no rows selected)
{
do this;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show an example of the output?

Comment: why is the output required over here?..its a simple case where whne there are no rows returned by an sql query.i want to chekc for `if(pm1_CS_missing_months is NULL )`

Comment: Is there any reason why you are calling the `sqlplus` command-line tool directly, rather than using a DBI interface?

Comment: NO...its n existing script where i need to do some changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scalar context (for example, in an `if` or `unless` condition), an array evaluates to the number of items in the array.  If your SQL result set contains no rows, the array will evaluate to 0 -- one flavor of falseness.

```
unless (@pm1_CS_missing_months){
   # No rows: do this...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with [DBD::Oracle](http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.24a/Oracle.pm).

Comment: Indeed, if you need more than the raw output of the command, the exec quotes are not enough, I'd go for DBI/DBD too.

Comment: And not only for checking the raw output of the command, but also to check whether the connection to the server was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you are using sqlplus, your output will depend on query. E.g., if there are no rows matching your criteria and you are doing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE`, you will get 0 in the output. If you are doing `SELECT * FROM TABLE` you will just get answer "no rows selected" which is not an empty output. So it's not enough to check if output is empty or zero, check also if there is string "no rows selected", too.